# Can I use callbacks to progressively display query results on a web page?

Tags: python, tornado

I am using tornado 2.3 (python 2.7.3) and am running a large batch of queries against a postgresql (9.2.1) database. This takes about 8 seconds to complete and I was wondering if I could use callbacks (using momoko connector to postgres) to progressively update the page with query results. I found the facebook example in the tornado demos folder, but that requires a click to refresh - but I was hoping to call a UI module for rendering when the query result was retrieved.

The current, (unfinished) code looks something like this:

```
    results = OrderedDict()
    cursor = yield gen.Task(self.db.execute, 'select location, string_of_words from source;')
    for verse in cursor.fetchall():
        queries = {}
        id = 0
        for word in verse[4].split(' '):
            queries[id] = ['select worddetailsbyword(%s)',(word,)]
            id += 1
        cursors = yield gen.Task(self.db.batch, queries)
        for key,cursor in cursors.items():
            worddata = {}
            if verse[0] not in results.keys():
                results[verse[0]] = []                                              
            results[verse[0]].append(cursor.fetchone())

    for loc, words in results.items():
        self.write("<h2>%s</h2>" % loc)
        for word in words:
            self.write("<div>%s</div>"%word[0])
```

Instead of waiting for all of this to complete, and *then* render in a template, could I implement a callback and have each query completion hit that callback and update the web page?

Comment: what is you use ioloop.add_timeout() http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/ae9b7527bf3d8948